# PdfBox: You did not close a PDF Document

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have closed the PDDocument in Apache PDFBox after convert image to pdf. I am getting the warning: You did not close PDF Document when I shutdown my instance.

Code:

```
private File imageToPDDocument(Path mergeDirectory, File file) throws IOException {
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
        float width = bimg.getWidth();
        float height = bimg.getHeight();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(file, doc);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        contentStream.close();
        File pdfFile = Files.createTempFile(mergeDirectory, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), ".tmp").toFile();
        doc.save(pdfFile);
        in.close();
        doc.close();
        return pdfFile;
    }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Make sure you have the latest jdk, and the latest PDFBox version (2.0.24).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i changed PDFBox to latest version and my jdk is 11.0.2. The message still appear (twice). Should the warning bother me?

Comment: The warning isn't that important, it warns about poor quality programming. However if it warns twice despite that you create only one document, then it means the code above isn't your actual code. Look for other `new PDDocument()` or `PDDocument.load()` occurrences in your code.

Comment: The current jdk11 is `11.0.13`, not `11.0.2`.

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation you have to close the pdf in a finally block:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#why-do-i-get-a-%22warning%3A-you-did-not-close-the-pdf-document%22%3F

It's worth a try.

Comment: spartalos, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)